# Apache Camel + JPA hangs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, apache-camel

After starting the route in a single thread and adding several records to the database, the route hangs on the insert operation. What could be wrong?

```java
@Component
public class FileHoRawDataRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    private final String fileConsumerEndpoint = "file://data";

    @Override
    public void configure() {
            from(fileConsumerEndpoint)
                    .routeId("file-to-postgres-ho")
                    .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()


                    .bean(DbRejectProcessingBean.class, "transformToRejected")
                    .to("jpa:org.example.etldatahandler.RawRejectedDataUnexpected");
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
public class DbRejectProcessingBean {

    public RawRejectedDataUnexpected transformToRejected(Exchange exchange) {
        RawRejectedDataUnexpected rawRejectedDataUnexpected = new RawRejectedDataUnexpected();

        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
        rawRejectedDataUnexpected.setData((String) exchange.getIn().getBody());
        rawRejectedDataUnexpected.setDataFormat("ho");

        return rawRejectedDataUnexpected;
    }

}
```

```java
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "raw_rejected_data_unexpected")
public class RawRejectedDataUnexpected {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    String data;

    @Column(name = "data_format")
    String dataFormat;

}
```

This is what I see when I terminate a frozen program (jsons are the values ​​of the "data" fields):

```
{"hoid":"A8909","activeflag":"1","natname":"ООО ЛЮБАША","latname":"LUBASHA","inn":"2434565412","okato":null,"okpo":"8976665","okved":"56.01","kpp":"444444444","kbk":null,"agt15":null,"agt19":null,"note":null,"k_id":null,"etl_op":null,"etl_err":"0","allow_pmnt":"active","allow_join":"0","open_date":"06.01.2024","ra_postal_code":"7876543","ra_address":"УЛ. ЛЕНИНА,8","ra_city":"САНКТ-ПЕТЕРБУРГ","ra_region":"САНКТ-ПЕТЕРБУРГ","ra_region_code":"","ra_country":"","la_postal_code":"105077","la_address":"УЛ. ЛЕНИНА,10","la_city":"САНКТ-ПЕТЕРБУРГ","la_region":"САНКТ-ПЕТЕРБУРГ","la_region_code":"","la_country":"","pay_priority":"B","pmf_bank_id":"ROS","fin_entity":null,"agr_ccy":null,"ccy_entity":null,"assigned_mc_sp":"","assigned_visa_sp":"","assigned_mir_sp":"","def_frame_h":"","pmf_business_gid":null,"office_entity":null,"bs_name":null,"bs_phone_number":null,"bs_emp_id2":null,"bs_email":null,"sa_name":null,"sa_phone_number":null,"sa_email":null,"agt_entity":null,"part_entity":null,"min_threshold":"","dir_name":"  ","dir_email":"","dir_phone":"","acc_name":null,"acc_email":null,"acc_phone":null,"party_id":"AurR3H","rec_created":null,"product_schema":"ROS-TRN-PS-RUR-001","source_code":null,"taxpayer_type":"","company_type":"bank","user_lk_email":null,"user_lk_name":null,"user_lk_phone":null}
{"hoid":"D1523","activeflag":"1","natname":"ООО АНДРЮША","latname":null,"inn":"2345456756","okato":null,"okpo":"14031701","okved":"47.11","kpp":"170101001","kbk":"00000000000000000130","agt15":"AurR3K","agt19":null,"note":"additional note","k_id":null,"etl_op":null,"etl_err":"0","allow_pmnt":"active","allow_join":"0","open_date":"06.01.2024","ra_postal_code":null,"ra_address":"","ra_city":null,"ra_region":null,"ra_region_code":"","ra_country":null,"la_postal_code":null,"la_address":"","la_city":null,"la_region":null,"la_region_code":"","la_country":null,"pay_priority":"A","pmf_bank_id":"ROS","fin_entity":null,"agr_ccy":null,"ccy_entity":null,"assigned_mc_sp":"","assigned_visa_sp":"","assigned_mir_sp":"","def_frame_h":"0","pmf_business_gid":null,"office_entity":null,"bs_name":"Сидоров Владимир Иванович","bs_phone_number":"+79998881123","bs_emp_id2":"BS11","bs_email":"sidorov_vladimir@ucscards_test.ru","sa_name":"","sa_phone_number":"","sa_email":"","agt_entity":null,"part_entity":null,"min_threshold":"","dir_name":null,"dir_email":null,"dir_phone":null,"acc_name":"  ","acc_email":"","acc_phone":"","party_id":"AurR3L","rec_created":"24.08.2023","product_schema":"ROS-TRN-PS-RUR-001","source_code":"UCS ГОЛОВНОЙ ОФИС","taxpayer_type":"","company_type":"bank","user_lk_email":"","user_lk_name":"  ","user_lk_phone":""}
{"hoid":"A1234","activeflag":"1","natname":"ООО \"ОРСИК\"","latname":"ORSIK","inn":"7535009573","okato":null,"okpo":null,"okved":"14.3","kpp":"753501001","kbk":null,"agt15":null,"agt19":null,"note":null,"k_id":null,"etl_op":null,"etl_err":"0","allow_pmnt":"active","allow_join":"0","open_date":"06.01.2024","ra_postal_code":"434276","ra_address":"СИРЕНЕВЫЙ БУЛ,42/22 КОРП.3","ra_city":"МОСКВА","ra_region":"МОСКВА","ra_region_code":"","ra_country":"","la_postal_code":"105077","la_address":"НОВОЧЕРЕМУШКИНСКАЯ УЛ.,10","la_city":"МОСКВА","la_region":"МОСКВА","la_region_code":"","la_country":"","pay_priority":"A","pmf_bank_id":"ROS","fin_entity":null,"agr_ccy":"RUR","ccy_entity":null,"assigned_mc_sp":"","assigned_visa_sp":"","assigned_mir_sp":"","def_frame_h":"","pmf_business_gid":null,"office_entity":null,"bs_name":"Сидоров Владимир Иванович","bs_phone_number":"+79998881123","bs_emp_id2":"BS11","bs_email":"sidorov_vladimir@ucscards_test.ru","sa_name":"","sa_phone_number":"","sa_email":"","agt_entity":null,"part_entity":null,"min_threshold":"","dir_name":"  ","dir_email":"","dir_phone":"","acc_name":"  ","acc_email":"","acc_phone":"","party_id":"AurR3E","rec_created":"05.01.2024","product_schema":"ROS-TRN-PS-RUR-001","source_code":"UCS ГОЛОВНОЙ ОФИС","taxpayer_type":"","company_type":"bank","user_lk_email":"","user_lk_name":"  ","user_lk_phone":""}
{"hoid":"00864","activeflag":"1","natname":"ИП СЕДЫХ МИХАИЛ НИКОЛАЕВИЧ","latname":null,"inn":"032385356896","okato":null,"okpo":"82063184","okved":"52.11.1","kpp":null,"kbk":null,"agt15":"AurR3O","agt19":null,"note":"1//","k_id":null,"etl_op":null,"etl_err":"0","allow_pmnt":"active","allow_join":"0","open_date":"07.01.2024","ra_postal_code":null,"ra_address":"","ra_city":"МОСКВА","ra_region":"МОСКВА","ra_region_code":"","ra_country":"","la_postal_code":null,"la_address":"","la_city":"МОСКВА","la_region":"МОСКВА","la_region_code":"","la_country":"","pay_priority":"A","pmf_bank_id":"ROS","fin_entity":null,"agr_ccy":null,"ccy_entity":null,"assigned_mc_sp":"","assigned_visa_sp":"","assigned_mir_sp":"","def_frame_h":"3","pmf_business_gid":null,"office_entity":null,"bs_name":"","bs_phone_number":"","bs_emp_id2":"BS61","bs_email":"","sa_name":"","sa_phone_number":"","sa_email":"","agt_entity":null,"part_entity":null,"min_threshold":"","dir_name":null,"dir_email":null,"dir_phone":null,"acc_name":"  ","acc_email":"","acc_phone":"","party_id":"AurR4t","rec_created":"30.04.2020","product_schema":"ROS-TRN-PS-RUR-001","source_code":"ПАО РОСБАНК","taxpayer_type":"","company_type":"bank","user_lk_email":"","user_lk_name":"  ","user_lk_phone":""}
{"hoid":null,"activeflag":"1","natname":"ИП СИДИНКИН ДМИТРИЙ ГЕРМАГЕНОВИЧ","latname":"SIDINKIN DMITRIY GERMAGENOVICH BUSINESSMAN","inn":"030600040519","okato":null,"okpo":"82063184","okved":"52.11.1","kpp":null,"kbk":null,"agt15":null,"agt19":null,"note":"1//","k_id":null,"etl_op":null,"etl_err":"0","allow_pmnt":"active","allow_join":"0","open_date":"07.01.2024","ra_postal_code":"671325","ra_address":"Владимирский проспект д.12","ra_city":"БУРЯТИЯ","ra_region":"03","ra_region_code":"","ra_country":"643","la_postal_code":"123456","la_address":"ул. Жуковского д.12","la_city":"БУРЯТИЯ","la_region":"78","la_region_code":"","la_country":"643","pay_priority":"A","pmf_bank_id":"ROS","fin_entity":null,"agr_ccy":null,"ccy_entity":null,"assigned_mc_sp":"","assigned_visa_sp":"","assigned_mir_sp":"","def_frame_h":"3","pmf_business_gid":"IRK","office_entity":null,"bs_name":"","bs_phone_number":"","bs_emp_id2":"BS61","bs_email":"","sa_name":"","sa_phone_number":"","sa_email":"","agt_entity":null,"part_entity":null,"min_threshold":"","dir_name":"  ","dir_email":"","dir_phone":"","acc_name":"  ","acc_email":"","acc_phone":"","party_id":"AurR4u","rec_created":"07.01.2024","product_schema":"ROS-TRN-PS-RUR-001","source_code":"ПАО РОСБАНК","taxpayer_type":"","company_type":"bank","user_lk_email":"","user_lk_name":"  ","user_lk_phone":""}
{"hoid":null,"activeflag":"1","natname":null,"latname":null,"inn":"6824651762","okato":null,"okpo":"82063184","okved":"52.11.1","kpp":null,"kbk":null,"agt15":null,"agt19":null,"note":"1//","k_id":null,"etl_op":null,"etl_err":"0","allow_pmnt":"active","allow_join":"0","open_date":"07.01.2024","ra_postal_code":"111111","ra_address":"ул. Боровая д.7к10","ra_city":"МОСКВА","ra_region":"МОСКВА","ra_region_code":"","ra_country":"","la_postal_code":"222222","la_address":"ул. Новочеремушкинская д.10","la_city":"МОСКВА","la_region":"МОСКВА","la_region_code":"","la_country":"","pay_priority":"A","pmf_bank_id":"ROS","fin_entity":null,"agr_ccy":null,"ccy_entity":null,"assigned_mc_sp":"","assigned_visa_sp":"","assigned_mir_sp":"","def_frame_h":"3","pmf_business_gid":"0001","office_entity":null,"bs_name":"","bs_phone_number":"","bs_emp_id2":"BS61","bs_email":"","sa_name":"","sa_phone_number":"","sa_email":"","agt_entity":null,"part_entity":null,"min_threshold":"","dir_name":"ИВАНОВ ИВАН ПЕТРОВИЧ","dir_email":"a@a.a","dir_phone":"89995556677","acc_name":"  ","acc_email":"","acc_phone":"","party_id":"AurR3P","rec_created":"07.01.2024","product_schema":"ROS-TRN-PS-RUR-001","source_code":"ПАО РОСБАНК","taxpayer_type":"","company_type":"bank","user_lk_email":"","user_lk_name":"  ","user_lk_phone":""}
2024-02-07T15:16:59.025+03:00  INFO 4956 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 4.2.0 (camel-1) is shutting down (timeout:45s)
2024-02-07T15:16:59.030+03:00  INFO 4956 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer  : Pausing Kafka record fetcher task running client ID consumer-96d1e2a7-768d-4eae-b512-28b488385020-1
2024-02-07T15:16:59.030+03:00  INFO 4956 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.c.component.kafka.KafkaFetchRecords  : A pause request was issued and the consumer thread will pause after current processing has finished
2024-02-07T15:16:59.034+03:00  INFO 4956 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 45 seconds. Inflights per route: [kafka-to-postgres-ho = 1]
2024-02-07T15:17:00.042+03:00  INFO 4956 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 44 seconds. Inflights per route: [kafka-to-postgres-ho = 1]
```

I tried using **jdbc**, **jdbc template**, **spring boot data jpa** with different isolation levels - nothing helped.